# Restart Power Supply on USB Port

Tags: windows-10, usb, embedded

I am working on a remote computer from home. I use various components on it, such as - gyroscope for example. The components are connected via USB HUB, which is directly connected to the computer. Unfortunately the gyroscope has frozen. I have to disconnect power to it at the port. I tried to programmatically turn the device off and on and delete and use scan to restore but that doesn't work.

I used pnputil command. I have also tried changing the settings in the registry in services_USBSTOR. I am using windows 10 on a daily basis.

Is there any other option where I disconnect the power and restore the device?

Comment: You can shut the machine down with the "shutdown" command and then start it using "wake on LAN".

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. The [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) tool, which implements port power switching on Linux, notes:

> While uhubctl compiles on Windows, USB power switching does not work on Windows because libusb is using winusb.sys driver, which according to Microsoft does not support [necessary USB control requests](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f680b63f-ca4f-4e52-baa9-9e64f8eee101). This may be fixed if libusb starts supporting different driver on Windows.

And in the linked MS TechNet forums page, a Microsoft developer has posted:

> There is no set interface. With extensive testing the USB team found per port power management to be very unreliable and stopped turning on the feature.

The thread was about third-party software, but the MSFT answer also strongly implies that Windows itself will not have any built-in hub power control feature, either.

But if the hub is not external-powered, rebooting the computer *might* cause it (and all other USB devices) to be turned off for a moment. If it is externally powered, you're probably out of luck.